# Shell script: Using variables makes command fails ( substituting values of variables manually ; command works fine )

Tags: shell-script, variable-substitution, eval

In a bash script:

```
    jenkins_folder=`cut -d "|" -f1 -s input.csv`
    jenkins_url='https://url.com:8181/jenkins/view/'
    echo "jenkins_folder : ${jenkins_folder}"
    for job in `java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s ${jenkins_url}${jenkins_folder} list-jobs ${jenkins_folder} `
do
    echo "Job name:: ${job} ****"
    java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s ${jenkins_url}${jenkins_folder} get-job ${job} > job.xml
done
```

is giving following output

```
jenkins_folder : Platform-X.X.X-SPO-MyPD-Integration-Dummy
 ****ame:: NH-AccountManagementAudit-Consumer-MyPD-Integration-DUMMY-Reporting
'; perhaps you meant 'NH-AccountManagementAudit-Consumer-MyPD-Integration-DUMMY-Reporting'?
```

And when I substitute values of all variables and run following command; it works fine

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s https://url.com:8181/jenkins/view/Platform-X.X.X-SPO-MyPD-Integration-Dummy get-job NH-AccountManagementAudit-Consumer-MyPD-Integration-DUMMY-Reporting > job.xml
```

I have wasted too much time on this. I even tried using eval function but no luck. Please help.

Thanks to @Kusalananda when I am trying to echo job name its printing output in wierd fashion.. I feel this is the root cause.. but not sure why that is happening

If I try to shorten the length of variable job (using substring); then it prints fine. Hence, if value of job is long; it is creating problem

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us how the variables get their values and what value each variable has.

Comment: I'm assuming you read the values of your variables, or at least of `job`, from a DOS text file?

Comment: @Kusalananda i am getting value of job as output from another command; updated the code

Comment: What happens if you add more text _after_ the output of `${job}` in that `echo` call?

Comment: @terdon edited. thanks.

Comment: @Kusalananda it gives wierd output. when i adds asteriks at lasts; it echos those in front

Comment: @Kusalananda probably as value is too long; so it is overflowing ??

Comment: No, the output of your `java` command contains a carriage-return character at the end.

Comment: Even if i skip java command; just echo is showing wrong value if value is long !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first issue is obvious: your url is `https://url.com:8181/jenkins/view`, so since it doesn't end with a slash, the value of `${jenkins_url}${jenkins_folder}`  is `https://url.com:8181/jenkins/viewPlatform-X.X.X-SPO-MyPD-Integration-Dummy`. So fix the url:

```
jenkins_url='https://url.com:8181/jenkins/view/'
```

Or, add the slash when you combine variables:

```
${jenkins_url}/${jenkins_folder}
```

Next, remember to always quote your variables:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s "${jenkins_url}${jenkins_folder}" get-job "$job" > job.xml
```

Your other issue is that it sounds like you have a file or command output with Windows line endings. That might be `input.csv` or anything else, but you will need to remove them. First run

```
dos2unix input.csv
```

Or, if you don't have `dos2unix`, run:

```
sed -i 's/\r//' input.csv
```

Then try your script again. If it still doesn't work, update your question with more details. If the `\r` is from your `jenkins-cli` command, try this:

```
jenkins_folder=`cut -d "|" -f1 -s input.csv`
jenkins_url='https://url.com:8181/jenkins/view/'
echo "jenkins_folder : ${jenkins_folder}"
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar \ 
 -s "${jenkins_url}/${jenkins_folder}" \
  list-jobs "$jenkins_folder" |
   sed 's/\r$//' | while read job
do
    echo "Job name:: ${job} ****"
    java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s ${jenkins_url}${jenkins_folder} get-job ${job} > job.xml
done
```

Comment: I missed slash in URL while masking the actual URL.  Editing the question. I tried using double quotes also; but still same output. I feel the problem we need to fix is that why during echo JobName it is putting asterikes in beginning !

Comment: and yes I did run your sed command; no change

Comment: @DeepakSinghal that is the windows line endings. You haven't told us anything about your system, so we can't know which part is causing it, but you have Windows somewhere in there.

Comment: file was originally coded on Mac and now running them on Linux.

Comment: If I try to shorten the length of variable job (using substring); then it prints fine. Hence, if value of job is long; it is creating problem

Comment: Their `java` command in the loop header outputs DOS text, so `$job` has a carriage-return at the end.

Comment: Some versions of Mac operating system use `\r` as line separator -- not `\n` and not `\r\n`. Google `mac line endings`: "On the Mac Classic (Mac systems using any system prior to Mac OS X), line-endings are terminated with a single carriage return (\r or CR). Mac OS X uses the UNIX convention.". dos2unix will not fix that -- you end up with one very long line.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant as far as I know, those are all very, very old pre-macOS as you say, and haven't been around for the past ~20 years (since 2002). I doubt it's worth mentioning these days.

Comment: @DeepakSinghal see updated answer for the case where the carriage returns are coming from your command.

Comment: Yes you are right; java itself was returning a carriage character.

Comment: @terdon  I didn't know how far back it went, but I recall seeing this issue in the wild earlier this year. I suspect Macs never die. "An Apple a day ... ".

Comment: Wow, really? I mean, I remember the days of having to deal with `\r\n`, `\n` and `\r` line endings, but I thought they were well and truly gone. In any case, frankly, if you are trying to run 20-year-old software on non-production systems (as these were) today, I feel you're on your own.